# Minecraft crash on Ubuntu 14.10/15.04

Tags: graphics, java, 15.04, crash, minecraft

Lately my Minecraft has been crashing with the error code:

```
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f4190031ac0, pid=26588, tid=139920718653184
```

I have an Nvidia graphics card but have no drivers installed as I have Nvidia Optimus. I am running Intel integrated graphics.

Here is my full crash log: http://pastebin.com/FuFeTCBC

I can supply more details if you wish, my theory was bad ram but a Memtest doesn't return any errors.

Comment: Why don't you go to https://help.mojang.com/ to get official help on the product you bought?  This is not really an Ubuntu question...

Answer (score 0):

SIGSEGV (SEGmentation Violation SIGnal) indicates a Segmentation fault, i.e. a program trying to access memory or other resources it mustn't.

This can be caused by bad memory, but as you said, memtest didn't find anything. The most likely cause for segfaults is a bug in a program (in this case Java) or a driver (e.g. the free Xorg nVidia driver, like you suggested) or a combination of incompatible pieces of software.

Just because you have hybrid graphics, you should install the proprietary nVidia driver, which AFAIK supports Optimus better than the free Xorg driver for nVidia chips. You can install it using the *Software & Updates* utility. Select the first unchecked suggestion for your graphics card in the *Additional drivers* tab. It should automatically install `nvidia-prime`, the Optimus support package.

If this doesn't solves your segfaults, the problem is somewhere else. In this case, install another Java version and try again with that. If you are lucky, you'll already have OpenJDK 7 installed, whose JRE you can try instead. Else, install another version of Oracle Java or OpenJDK and try with that.

If even this doesn't work, it's most likely a bug in a native library used by Minecraft. Ask Mojang in this case.